# Simple method to find the number of seconds between two (non-standard) date formats?

Tags: bash, date

I have a program which outputs dates in the following form:

`Thu Mar  5 09:15:27 2015`

This is very close to the output of `date` in Linux, but this format does not include time zone. Assuming I can capture the string `Thu Mar  5 09:15:27 2015` as `date1` and the string `Thu Mar  5 09:30:58 2015` as `date2` in `bash`, how can I get the number of seconds between those two dates (without having to write my own bash/python/etc. script to do the calculation)?

Comment: Difference in what time zone?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. Assume that `date1` and `date2` are in the same time zone, in which case the time zone is irrelevant.

Comment: Irrelevant? Are you aware that Daylight Saving Time changes don't happen at the same moment in all the timezones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "without calculation". The following does the calculation...

```
date1="Thu Mar 5 09:15:27 2015"
date2="Thu Mar 5 09:30:58 2015"

printf "%s\n" $(( $(date -d "$date2" "+%s") - $(date -d "$date1" "+%s") ))
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe it was confusing but I just meant having to do calculations by hand: finding nsecs1, nsecs2, nmins1, nmins2, ... etc and having to do the subtraction myself.

Comment: Maybe it's the version of `date` or because I'm using `zsh` (macOS Catalina) but this doesn't work for me. Running `$ date -d "Thu Mar 5 09:15:27 2015" +%s` outputs `usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`. The date format appears to be completely different.

Answer (score 2):

Without the timezone information, you can't always give the correct answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
export TZ
for TZ in America/New_York Europe/Prague ; do
    d1=$(date -d 'Mar 8 01:59:59 2015' +%s)
    d2=$(date -d 'Mar 8 03:00:01 2015' +%s)
    echo "$TZ: $((d2-d1))"
done
```

Comment: choroba, doesn't a missing timezone mean the locally (configured) timezone? Then the result would be consistent for the defined locale. In other words, a difference in time stamps (both from the same locale) should give the expected result.

Comment: @Janis: If the times come from a different timezone than the locally (configured) one, this could break. Try `TZ=America/New_York date -d 'Mar 8 02:00:00 2015'`

Comment: Sure. But why do you think the OP would compare time stamps from different locales? Possible, but there's no indication that the OP has such a case.

Comment: @Janis: Note that for existing times, the script answers the question.

Comment: @Janis No, that's not enough. Consider `Oct 25 00:59:59 2015` and `Oct 25 00:59:59 2015` (yes, that's the same date twice) in `Europe/London`. Is the difference 0… or is one from before DST was switched off and one from after, making the difference 1 hour? You **need** a DST indication on the time, otherwise you can't always know what it refers to.

Comment: @Gilles, point taken. But there's obviously nothing that can be done, since the time zone is not part of the given time stamp data.

Answer (score 1):

Note that some other shells have the feature built in:

#### zsh

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
date1='Thu Mar 5 09:15:27 2015'
date2='Thu Mar 5 09:30:58 2015'
for v (date{1,2}) strftime -rs $v '%a %b %d %T %Y' ${(P)v}
echo $((date2 - date1))
```

See [`info zsh strftime`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-strftime) and [`info zsh flags`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-flags_002c-parameter-expansion) for the `P` parameter expansion flag for details.

#### ksh93

```
date1='Thu Mar 5 09:15:27 2015'
date2='Thu Mar 5 09:30:58 2015'
echo "$(($(printf '%(%s)T - %(%s)T' "$date2" "$date1")))"
```

See `man <(printf --nroff 2>&1)` within ksh for details.

(for both, dates are assumed to be in the local timezone).

Comment: could you please comment the `${(P)v}` part? I don't know how to look for it on google as it is mostly syntax characters and doesn't look like a "standard" variable substitution (what does (P) stand for?). And likewise: `%(%s)T` ? (the inside %s should receive the value in "$date2" ? does %(some date here)T yeld an epoch?) (I can't test using those 2 shells)

Comment: @OlivierDulac, see edit.

Comment: Thank you! It seems similar to bash's variable indirect expansion : `${!var}` (which, if `var=foo`, will fetch value of `$foo`. and `${!v}` : will expand instead to every variable names starting with `v`). And for the `%(...)T` printf construct : it is indeed from ksh93 and explained for exemple in https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2018/05/bash-printf-t-option.html

Comment: Yes, though note that bash's `${!var}` does almost the opposite of what `${!var}` did in ksh93. bash added `%(...)T` to its own `printf` recently but doesn't do the date parsing that ksh93 does. In general you don't want to read the documentation of one shell to learn about another shell.

Comment: I agree, and thank you for all the answer and further clarifications.